# How to set up an exponential distribution?

Tags: r

The time taken to get from A to B is X minutes, where X is distributed as 30 plus an exponential random variable with mean 12.

I tried:

```
X = 30 + dexp(x, rate = 12, log = FALSE)
```

However it came up with an error as `X` is undefined. How do I get round this?

Comment: The `rexp` command samples randomly from an exponential distribution. For example, `rexp(10,1/12)` pulls 10 values from an exponential distribution with a mean of 12. The second argument is expressed as a rate.

Comment: @mysteRious, post as an answer?

Comment: I was on the edge of "not really feeling whether it was answer-y enough"... thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rexp` command samples randomly from an exponential distribution. For example, `rexp(10,1/12)` pulls 10 values from an exponential distribution with a mean of 12. The second argument is expressed as a rate:

```
> rexp(10,1/12)
 [1]  4.379934  1.449683  6.959518 11.319050 15.363749  1.426965  1.442269
 [8] 19.788934  2.764713  9.236977
> hist(rexp(10,1/12))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!